# can anyone help me for my css script,set height: 100% for sidebar(aside)

Tags: css

can anyone help me, why i can't set height: 100% for my aside (sidebar)??i have tried some ways to solve this, like set the height of html and body to 100%, or position to absolute, etc
but no one works for me

```css
aside article > h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
aside:not(.nav){
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
aside {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
 this is my htmlc code for aside, something wrong with this???
```

```html
<aside>
 <article>
 <h1>Yudistira S</h1>
 <div class="header">
  <img src="space.png" width="50" height="50"/>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p>Yudistira</p>
  <p>Last Login : 2 Weeks Ago</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
   <li class="navaside"><a href="#">UI Element</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Tabs and Panels</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Notification</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Pprogressbars</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Wizard</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="navaside satu"><a href="#">Extra Pages</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Invoice</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Component</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Messages and Tasks</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   
 </article>
</aside>
```

Comment: post also some html to go with your css so that we could recreate the problem

Comment: i have renewed my question, add my html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a height equal to window size use the vh(view height)unit instead .

```
height:100vh;
```